# how do you connect project 2010 client to project 2010 server?

Tags: microsoft-project

I can't seem to find the button to connect the project 2010 client to the server.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directions are on this page.](http://epmcentral.com/articles/ps10step6.php)

Basically, when you log in, select the server name from the dropdown instead of the local computer.

Comment: Glad it worked.